# How can I multiply a certain amount of prime numbers?

Tags: java

How would I go about writing a program that when you input a number, say 5 for instance, it will give me the output of the first 5th prime numbers multiplied together?

For instance, 5 should return 2*3*5*7*11 = 2310. this is part of a big project and this part has me stumped.

Comment: So if I enter 23 it will multiply 17*19*23*29*31? So it is getting the two previous prime numbers and two others prime numbers after it?  If that is so what happens if you enter 2?

Comment: What exactly has you stumped?  Can you please post any code you have so far, plus any error messages, exception stack traces, or incorrect output you have?

Comment: Good luck on your homework or interview assignment!!

Comment: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 1):

Not going to give you a complete answer, just guide you in the right direction.

1. Find the first `i` prime numbers. This can be done by brute force, or using some smarter algorithm like [Sieve_of_Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

    (A naive algorithm will just check each number iteratively to see if it's a prime by checking if it is divisable by all lower numbers, abort when you found the correct amount of prime numbers).
2. Multiply the numbers. This might be a very large number, so I suggest using a [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) object for it.

Implementing each of these parts should be fairly easy, and is left for you.

Answer (score -1):

this function can help you

```
private ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>() ; 
public void primeMultiply(int j){
     boolean isPrime = false; 
     if(j<4){
           primes.add(1); 
           primes.add(2); 
           primes.add(3); 
           double mutliply = 1 ; 
           for(Integer int1 : primes){
               multiply *= int1 ; 
           }
           System.out.println("Multiply=" +  multiply) ; 
           return ; 
     }else{
           primes.add(1); 
           primes.add(2); 
           primes.add(3); 
           for(int k=4 ; k<=j ; k++){
               if(k%2 == 0) continue;
               isPrime = true ;  
               else{
                   for(int q=2 ; q<k-1 ; q++){
                       if(k%q==0){
                          isPrime = flase; break; 
                       }
                   }
               }
             if(isPrime){primes.add(k) ;} 
             isPrime= false ; 
           }
          for(Integer int1 : primes){
               multiply *= int1 ; 
           }
           System.out.println("Multiply=" +  multiply) ; 
           return ;

     }
}
```